# Only show certain variables in Stargazer output (Python, not R)

Tags: python, stargazer

I am using Stargazer for Python (not R).

I trained six `statsmodels` models and stored them in a list named `models`.

I want to filter the independent variables that are displayed by Stargazer. How can this be done?

This is what I have so far:

```py
# Import
from stargazer.stargazer import Stargazer

# There are six statsmodels objects in `models`
len(models)
> 6

# What I'm currently doing
star_out = Stargazer(models)
```

I'm looking for a method with which I can select only a subset of the independent variables used to train each model. Say, something along the lines of `star_out.select_covariates(['var1','var8'])`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .covariate_order() function to select which covariates you want to display.

```
star_out.covariate_order(['var1','var8'])
```

see more at https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/blob/master/examples.ipynb